# Can we style a class inside another class in css?

Tags: html, css

I’m practising some codepen projects , in one project they used a .class{} inside another .class{} for example-

```
Code

.cube{
    width:2em;
    height:2em;
    
    .side{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#;
    }
}
```

Seemed to work fine for them.  It doesn’t work for me , exact same text editor , exact same code . What is happening ?

And also , what is the above mentioned thing called ? And how does it work ?

Comment: Look up "SCSS".

Comment: You looking for precompiling css like SASS or LESS.

Answer (score 2):

That CSS structure implies that they're using a CSS preprocessor, such as [LESS](https://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/).

Currently such syntax isn't valid CSS, though the [CSS Nesting Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/) is currently in working draft status; so it will – likely – be implemented in the future.

It's worth noting that, while *nesting* syntax is being developed for CSS, that syntax is different; from the previously-linked documentation:

```
table.colortable {
  & td {
    text-align:center;
    &.c { text-transform:uppercase }
    &:first-child, &:first-child + td { border:1px solid black }
  }
  & th {
    text-align:center;
    background:black;
    color:white;
  }
}
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
table.colortable td {
  text-align:center;
}
table.colortable td.c {
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
table.colortable td:first-child, table.colortable td:first-child+td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
table.colortable th {
  text-align:center;
  background:black;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: Although CSS nesting will not support that particular syntax since it can't be parsed efficiently enough. The inner selector would have to be `& .side`.

Comment: @Alohci, that's a good point, I'll be editing that in momentarily (though I was unaware specifically of the efficiency issues).